# PHP add value to database depending on the amount of inputs for this table

Tags: php, sql, database, input

Sorry guys, this is so difficult for me to explain. I have a database for recipes. And in this database I have a table for ingredients, a table for recipes and a recipeIngredients table where they are linked.

A basic Form I have will have recipe name as an input, and an input for an ingredient. There will be a plus button beside this input bar and if the user clicks the plus button, another input box will appear where another ingredient will be entered.

So far,my code only works when I only have one ingredient for the recipe being sent to the database. Is there a way I can have this form sending multiple ingredients to the ingredients table when I click submit?

Here is my html form:

```
        <form class="recipe-form" method="post">
                   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                       <label>Name :</label>
                       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name">
                   </div>

                   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                       <label>ingredients :</label>
                       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ingredientName" />
                   </div>
                       <button type="submit" name="submit" value=" Submit">
                           Login</button>
       </form>
```

Here is the php I have made for entering one ingredient. I am not sure at all how to approach this to allow the user to enter multiple values into the ingredients table.

```
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $ingredientName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ingredientName']);
    $sql1 = ("INSERT INTO recipes(recipe_ID, user_ID, name) VALUES (NULL, '117', '$name')");
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    $recipe_ID = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    $sql2 = ("INSERT INTO ingredients(ingredient_ID, name) VALUES (NULL, '$ingredientName')");
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    $ingredient_ID = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    $sql3 = ("INSERT INTO recipeingredient(recipe_ID, ingredient_ID) VALUES('$recipe_ID', '$ingredient_ID')");
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
```

Comment: *"So far,my code only works when I only have one ingredient for the recipe being sent to the database. Is there a way I can have this form sending multiple ingredients to the ingredients table when I click submit?"* - What do you mean by that exactly? Do you want to have more inputs or treat one input that can handle multiple values?

Comment: Sorry. At the moment the form has one input for ingredient. So if I have a 'plus button' which adds another input field to the form for ingredient (now have two ingredient fields) how exactly would I then have this add both ingredients to the database instead of just one. Does this explain it better?

Comment: *"So if I have a 'plus button' which adds another input field to the form for ingredient"* - You're going to need to use Javascript for that and I am not the guy for this.

Comment: `name="ingredientName[]"` on each ingredient field will transform it in an array of values and you will use a foreach on the ingredientName in PHP to insert the values

Comment: @Shauna Someone submitted an answer below, see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do ,

```
<form class="recipe-form" method="post">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Name :</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>ingredients :</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name[ingredients][]" />
</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value=" Submit">Login</button>
```

In your php, you should now have an array that you can loop over and create a new array of information and insert into database.